# How to iterate over object sent via AJAX JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
var parameters = { "parameters" :
    [
        {
            "key": "feedbackSource",
            "value": "foo"
        }, {
            "key": "status",
            "value": "foo"
        }, {
            "key": "feedbackType",
            "value": "foo"
        }
    ]
};
```

console.log(JSON.stringify(parameters)) shows:

```
{"parameters":[{"key":"feedbackSource","value":"foo"},{"key":"status","value":"foo"},{"key":"feedbackType","value":"foo"}]}
```

**AJAX:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myPage.aspx/MyMethod",
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

**Method:**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(object parameters)
{

}
```

### Question: How do I iterate over that object in C# to get the contents?

I have tried:

```
foreach (var p in (IEnumerable) parameters)
{
    foreach (var x in (IEnumerable) p)
    {
        var test = x;
    }
}
```

But `test` on the first iteration is a Key Value pair, with `Key = "key"` and `Value = "feedbackSource"`.  On the second iteration, `Key = "value"` and `Value = "foo"`

And that doesn't seem like the correct way to iterate over the object.  I would expect the `Key = "feedbackSource"` and `Value = "foo"`.

Comment: What framework are you using on the server? Is it an ASMX WebService?

Comment: @MartinHN - this is ASP.NET v 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "How do I iterate over that object in C# to get the contents"

After a good discussion with @Devlin about this - the following conclusion has been reached:

### Current JSON data structure

The JSON string that is being generated (from the page) is a little confusing to say the least.

The existing data structure of

> `{ "parameters" :
>       [
>           {
>               "key": "feedbackSource",
>               "value": "foo"
>           }, {
>               "key": "status",
>               "value": "foo"
>           }, {
>               "key": "feedbackType",
>               "value": "foo"
>           }
>       ]
>   };`

Was very confusing and obfuscated the data somewhat - making it very hard to traverse and iterate the objects inside.

It appeared to be of key:(key/value) pairs/pairs (*wait, what?*)

I proposed to structure a proper key/value pair structure to the JSON firstly (from within the page).

Like so:

```
{ "parameters" : 
    [ 
        { 
            "feedbackSource" : "foo" 
        }, 
        { 
            "status" : "foo" 
        }, 
        { 
            "feedbackType" : "foo" 
        } 
    ] 
}
```

---

### What is the ModelBinder doing?

As per @Devlin's screenshot: [image: debug screenshot]

The ModelBinder was *cleverly* assiging `parameter` as a `Dictionary<string, object>`, because it recognised the JSON as key/value pairs *- in which the values were yet again key value pairs*.

Obviously, every type in C# derives from `object`, so accepting this was just boxing it in an `object`.

Thus why other suggestions of casting to a `string` weren't successful.

ASP.NET has a ModelBinder which is able to detect types of objects passed to methods, to make it easier when getting data out in the method.

---

### Passing in/using the right type

#### Suggestion 1

Cast the `object parameter` in the `MyMethod` signature to a `Dictionary<string, string>` (do it safely, where possible)

Like so:

```
var paramsDict = parameters as Dictionary<string, object>;
if (paramsDict != null)
{
    // Iterate over the dictionary in here
}
```

#### Suggestion 2

Seeing as we know that the `object parameters` is already of type `Dictionary<string, object>` (thanks to some wizardry by the ModelBinder), we could just use this type in the `MyMethod` signature, instead.

Like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void MyMethod(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    // Iterate in here
}
```

---

### Iterating the data

Now that you've got a nice and easy to use `Dictionary<string, object>`, it is simple to iterate over it and grab the values from there.

Like this:

```
foreach (var param in paramsDict) // or "... in parameters" if you're using suggestion 2
{
    var key = param.Key;
    var value = param.Value;

    // Manipulate/persist the data
}
```

---

It's up to you how you then manipulate/persist the data, but this should give you a starting point of getting the data from your JSON object.

**Summary**

- Change your JSON structure to be "proper" key/value pairs
- Default ModelBinder is able to assign the JSON as a C# `Dictionary<string, object>`
- Either change the `MyMethod` signature to accept `Dictionary<string, object>` type for `parameter`, or cast the `parameter` object to a `Dictionary` (both should work the same)
- Iterate each item in the `Dictionary`. You can then access the `Key`s and `Value`s of each item, and then manipulate the data however you wish

**Furthermore**
Given that your JSON string is passing in key/value pairs of `string` and `string`, I suspect that you may safely use `Dictionary<string, string>` to be picked up by the ModelBinder, or when casting etc. *confirmation may be needed on this, however*

Hope this helps, and best of luck in your project! :)

Comment: `if (paramsString != null)` is false.  In other words, paramString is null.  Why?

Comment: It's a safe casting check, if the `parameters` `object` is not (for some reason) a string. Casting using `parameters as string` will not throw an exception (like the `(string)parameters` cast), and instead will create a `null` `string` - hence the `null` check.

Comment: When I cast parameters to string, it is null.  Here's what I see in debug: http://imgur.com/0NUtqzf

Comment: Then that would explain why when you change the method signature to `string parameters` the binding is not working correctly - by the looks of it, your binder *may have* actually realised that it's already of type `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

Comment: If the above is true, then you could simply cast the `parameters` to that type, and iterate over it in a similar way as above: `foreach (var param in paramsKVPs) { key = param.Key; value = param.Value; ... }`

Comment: casting to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` yields null as well.

Comment: I would suggest seeing what type it is first, then. Just create a Type object and inspect it in your debugger: `Type parametersType = parameters.GetType();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117461/discussion-between-geoff-james-and-devlin-carnate).

Answer (score 1):

```
var parameters =
            {
                "parameters":
                [
                    {"feedbackSource": "foo", "status": "foo", "feedbackType": "foo"}
                ]
            };
```

create below class

```
public class mComputedProp
{
    public string feedbackSource { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string feedbackType { get; set; }
}

public class mcomputedprops
    {
        [JsonProperty("parameters")]
        public List<mComputedProp> mprops = new List<mComputedProp>();
    }
```

Modify your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("getComputedProperty", "Home")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ listjson: JSON.stringify(parameters) })                    
            });


[WebMethod]
    public void getComputedProperty(string listjson)
        {
            mcomputedprops mod = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<mcomputedprops>(listjson);
            string asdf = mod.mprops[0].feedbackSource.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I want to avoid this, if at all possible.  I would like to send an object.

Comment: Modified the answer based on your comment

Comment: How do I enumerate over `data` once I'm inside MyMethod?

Comment: data.feedbackSource, data.status, data.feedbackType

Comment: All of the values are null ?  `var test = data.feedbackSource;` shows `test is null`

Comment: Modified the json string to make it work. You have to implement Newtonsoft.JSON in your classes